# Jump from else to the beginning of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new at Stackoverflow and just at the beginning of learning programming with Python 3.3. I just wanted to show you my code with the following question.

The whole script will be used to make a copy of my blog from the ftp server to my local hard drive.

I want to check if a folder with the excat name already exists. If yes I want to wait 60 seconds and repeat. 60 seconds because after that it is excluded that I run into the same problem.

I know you will ask yourself why will this dude make more than one copy of his blog in one minute.. The point is that I want to learn how to check those situations I could run in.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
def create_backup_folder(ftp, destination_directory):
    temp = time.localtime()
    current_datetime = "{}-{}-{}_{}-{}".format(temp.tm_year, temp.tm_mon, temp.tm_mday, temp.tm_hour, temp.tm_min)
    if not os.path.exists(destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime):
        os.mkdir(destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime, 0o777)
        print("Backup folder successfully created!")
    else:
        print("Folder already exists with the current date_time_stamp. Wait 60 seconds...")
        time.sleep(60)
        #create_backup_folder(ftp, destination_directory)
    newDir = destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime
    download_directory(ftp, newDir)
```

The commented-out line gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

I'd appreciate your response! Many thanks!

Comment: There's no call to `sendall` in your code; perhaps the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to retry an operation, a for or while loop inside the function is handy. In your case, you only want to make two attempts, so a for loop works well. I tried to tidy the code a bit, but you end up with something like:

```
def create_backup_folder(ftp, destination_directory):
    for i in range(2):
        temp = time.localtime()
        current_datetime = "{}-{}-{}_{}-{}".format(temp.tm_year, temp.tm_mon, temp.tm_mday, temp.tm_hour, temp.tm_min)
        target_dir = destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime
        if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
            os.mkdir(target_dir, 0777)
            print("Backup folder successfully created!")
            return target_dir
        else:
            time.sleep(60)
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not create backup directory in two tries")
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the loop outside of the function, e.g.:

```
def create_backup_folder(ftp, destination_directory):
    temp = time.localtime()
    current_datetime = "{}-{}-{}_{}-{}".format(temp.tm_year, temp.tm_mon, temp.tm_mday, temp.tm_hour, temp.tm_min)
    if not os.path.exists(destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime):
        os.mkdir(destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime, 0o777)
        print("Backup folder successfully created!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Folder already exists with the current date_time_stamp. Wait 60 seconds...")
        return False
    newDir = destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime
    download_directory(ftp, newDir)


done = False
while not done:
    done = create_backup_folder(foo, bar)
```

I'd also recommend coming up with some kind of termination condition, so that it doesn't run forever.

Comment: I tried your solution too but broke up because I was not able to call the function `download_directory(ftp, newDir)`. I tried several positions but always got stucked. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully build in tdelaney's suggestion into my script.

Here is the full solution of it:

*(I just had to put the call of the funtion `create_backup_folder` into the 2nd loop)*

```
# Create backup folder with date and time stamp
def create_backup_folder(ftp, destination_directory):
    for i in range(2):
        temp = time.localtime()
        current_datetime = "{}-{}-{}_{}-{}".format(temp.tm_year, temp.tm_mon, temp.tm_mday, temp.tm_hour, temp.tm_min)
        target_dir = destination_directory + 'bak_' + current_datetime
        if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
        os.mkdir(target_dir, mode=0o777)
        print("Backup folder successfully created!")
        download_directory(ftp, target_dir)
        #return target_dir
        else:
            print("Please be patient")
            time.sleep(60)
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not create backup directory in two tries")
```